# ArcGIS Online: Using a subset of polygons from a feature service

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, feature-service

I am trying to work with a feature service that provides polygons for all property boundaries in Victoria, Australia. The feature service is [available here](https://delwp.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1164ada5f82e45879a610630f88ef6b1#overview).

I'd like to share a map within my organisation that displays a relevant *subset* of these polygons. I'd also like to add my own data/attributes to those relevant property polygons. Crucially, if the original feature service is updated and property boundaries are changed, my web map needs to reflect that change.

For example, only the buildings within the selected area should be visible, and if one of those polygon shapes changes in the Vicmap feature service, it should change in my web map too:

[image]

I've toyed with using ArcGIS Pro to perform the selection and attribute adding, and then scheduling automatic updates to my Web Map, but this feels like an overly complex solution to what is essentially a selection + join operation.

Is what I'm attempting possible? Does someone have any light that they can shed?